# List selected option in different cells in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

[Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jb5Us.png)

Hi, I want to list down the selected option at second box. For example(option 1), when I put Y on pineapple and orange. It will automatically shown in second box and in separate column. Anyone know how I can do that? Any formula that i can use?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula:

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER($A$2:$A$6,XLOOKUP($A9,$B$1:$F$1,$B$2:$F$6)="y"))
```

[image]

`XLOOKUP` is searching the header row of the top table for the value found in column A of the bottom table. It is then returning rows 2 through 6 for the column where it finds that option value.

By comparing this `XLOOKUP` result with a "y", we are creating an array of TRUE/FALSE, where the array item is TRUE if the corresponding row in the top table contains a y for that option.

`FILTER` is saying "filter column A of the top table (i.e. the fruit names) where the corresponding array item in the `XLOOKUP` result is TRUE". In other words, return the fruits which have a "y" in the option column.

`TRANSPOSE` is simply turning the original result of `FILTER`, which is vertical, to a horizontal array.

[image]